# How to convert alphanumeric into numeric in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Hello all my df1 looks like this

```
PID        Sex
TNGP0001    M
TNGP1234    M
TNGP4567    F
123         F
567         M
```

And my df2 looks like this

```
PID        V1
TNGP0001       54
TNGP1234       52
123            57
567            58
```

I want to merge df1 with df2  and want output like

Expected Results:

```
PID        Sex  V1
TNGP0001    M   54
TNGP1234    M   52
123         F   57
567         M   58
```

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: try `dplyr::inner_join(df1,df2,by="PID")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do

```
df <- data.frame(PID=df1$PID, Sex=df1$Sex, V1=df2$V1)
```